# PHP webmail framework

Tags: php, html, webmail

Is there any easy to implement webmail framework out there? It doesn't matter if it's free or commercial, as long as it's good and can be implemented to a custom design really fast.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roundcube have support form themes and api for building extensions.

http://roundcube.net/about#features

Comment: RoundCube is really good and easy to modify the CSS :) I have it up and running now with my own design, took me a couple of hours.

Answer (score 1):

[Squirrelmail](http://squirrelmail.org/) is written in PHP, and is time-tested and stable.  [Modifying CSS for custom design](http://squirrelmail.org/wiki/StyleSheets) is limited, however.

Answer (score 1):

Squirrel mail is pretty decent. You might want to ask this in serverfault? But I've set up a webmail server before and squirrelmail was decently customizable. I change the logo and some stuff, I didn't go all out on it. Perhaps you can ask them, squirrelmail peeps, about it too.